# Reducer doesn´t bring initialState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am using a reducer to manage a varied of states on my application. But every time I add a new key to my initial state, like this:

```js
const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  archiveTypes: [],
  archiveType: {
    id: null,
    name: '',
    local: '',
    description: '',
  }
}
```

The initialState never shows the new information until I dispatch some info to the reducer.

Is there a way to make it already start with all the information?

My full code:

```js
import * as actionTypes from 'actions';
import produce from 'immer';

const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  archiveTypes: [],
  archiveType: {
    id: null,
    name: '',
    local: '',
    description: '',
  }
}

const archiveTypeReducer = produce((draft, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {

    case actionTypes.ARCHIVE_TYPE_GET_ALL_SUCCESS: {
      draft.loading = false;
      try {
        draft.archiveTypes = action.payload
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(`REDUCER ERROR ${err}`)
      }
      return draft;
    }

    case actionTypes.ARCHIVE_TYPE_GET_BY_ID_SUCCESS: {
      draft.loading = false;
      try {
        draft.archiveType = action.payload
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(`REDUCER ERROR ${err}`)
      }
      return draft;
    }

    case actionTypes.ARCHIVE_TYPE_REQUEST_FAILURE: {
      draft = initialState
      return draft
    }

    default: {
      return draft;
    }
  }
}, initialState);

export default archiveTypeReducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Redux app, your initial state is exactly that: your **initial** state.  If you want to change your state after your page loads, you have to dispatch an action to do so.

If you want a way to completely reset your state, then you'll need to create a `RESET_ALL_STATE` action (or in your case, it seems your `actionTypes.ARCHIVE_TYPE_REQUEST_FAILURE` restores the initial state).  But really that's pretty abnormal; normally you'll just want to use an `ADD_SPECIFIC_DATA` action.

Comment: Yes, but  I am adding fields to initalState, but they doesnt appear

Comment: When you say "adding fields", what exactly do you mean?  Like ... `initialState.foo = 1`?

Comment: No it´s adding a field to initialState like this: 

before: 

`initialState={
    a: [],
    b: []
}`

after:

`initialState = {
    a: [],
    b: [],
    c: []
}`

Comment: So in other words, you're not doing `initialState.c = []`, you're changing the Javascript code and refreshing the page?  In that case **NOTHING** should be sticking around from the previous version of `initialState`.  When a browser refreshes, it should start with a completely clean `initialState`, based on the latest version of your file.  The only way the old version could stick around (that I could think of) is if you have some sort of caching issue with Create React App/Webpack, and it's not clearing out the old files when it generates new ones.

Comment: Maybe that´s the problem. Do you know how can I check that? And to get the new initial state, isnt possible that i should make a dispatch request?

Comment: For the caching stuff, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49604821/cache-busting-with-cra-react.  But for your initial data you *do not* want to make a dispatch.  Dispatch is for dispatching *actions*, which is how you *change* existing store data.  Initial data is something separate; it's not something you set with an action, it's just how your store starts out, and you pass it directly when you make that store.

Comment: All right, I´ll talke a look at it! Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can call action in method of component live circle, like componentDidMount. Or react hooks, useEffect
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: Call a dispatch?

Comment: Yes. For example you have mapDispatchToProps like that: setFoo: dispatch({ type: 'SET_FOO' }). And if you use class component, put setFoo() into the componentDidMount. It will call your action when componen did mount, it means whet component shows in view screen.

Comment: Yes, in some pages I use these technique, but I need to get the initial state without a dispatch. Just using the reducer, it´s that possible?

Answer (score 0):

And one thing, you forgot set initiasState as default state(draft).
produce((draft = initialState, action).